# Data that has been edited is not updated into database

Tags: laravel

i had some problem for updating my data, i was able to catch the file that was going to be updated by using dd and they are there, but when i was submitting the form the data remains the same, nothing change and no error whatsoever, here are my store(update) controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request);

    $request->validate([
        'attachment_name' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:10048',
    ]);

    $storedImage = $request->attachment_name->store('public/image/');

    MediaOrder::updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->id],
    [
        'nomor'=> $request->nomor,
        'nomor_reference'=> $request->nomor_reference,
        'periode_start'=> $request->periode_start,
        'periode_end'=> $request->periode_end,
        'category_id'=> $request->category_id,
        'type_id'=> $request->type_id,
        'agency_code'=> $request->agency_code,
        'agency_name'=> $request->agency_name,
        'advertiser_code'=> $request->advertiser_code,
        'advertiser_name'=> $request->advertiser_name,
        'brand_code'=> $request->brand_code,
        'brand_name'=> $request->brand_name,
        'nett_budget'=> $request->nett_budget,
        'gross_value'=> $request->gross_value,
        'nett_cashback'=> $request->nett_cashback,
        'nett_bundling'=> $request->nett_bundling,
        'version_code'=> $request->version_code,
        'spot'=> $request->spot,
        'accountexecutive_name'=> $request->accountexecutive_name,
        'group_id'=> $request->group_id,
        'userto_name'=> $request->userto_name,
        'notes'=> $request->notes,
        'attachment_name'=> $storedImage,
    ]);

    flash_success_store('Media Order successfully updated.');

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return redirect_ajax_notification('media-order.index');
    } else {
        return redirect_ajax('media-order.index');
    }
}
```

i already find and change it myself but to no avail, maybe someone can have a solution?, thank you for your time.

Comment: @NicoHaase i was stuck at updating the image, i was able to create new order, and the image was succesfully inserted into 'public/image' but when im trying to update it doesn't work and i've tried previous store(update) code and the attachment file just ended up being an C:/xampp/temp file

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason that the model is not updated or entered is that you do not make the attributes fillable in the model itself. Go to your model MediaOrder and check if you have set all attributes fillable.

`protected $fillable = [..];`

Comment: hello there ,all attributes is already fillable in the model, but it seems the 'attachment_name' doesn't show up when im trying to dd($request)

Comment: @Vtych Ok. Change your validation rule for `attachment_name` "only as a test". Instead of `"required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:10048'"` just `"required"` . You will get the data?

Comment: i was able to get all data except the attachment_name, the file was okay when i was tyring to create, but when updated, the attachment_name become a C:/xampp/tempt file